# Want to change my.ini file in sql for some session only

Tags: php, mysql

I am using MATCH(col1,col2) AGAINST("text") query to search things fastly. But due tto its limitation of full stop words. I need to change my.ini file. I need to add this much of code in my.ini file.

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len = "1"
ft_stopword_file =""
```

I want to add commands for my application only. Because it may happens my.ini file will be used by many other application. I want some php script with particular session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to set this dynamically at runtime, as fulltext settings can be changed before starting the server.

As far I see you will need a dedicated server instance for this site, you can do that by starting on some other port than the default one.

And you can pass the param at the command line when starting the server

```
mysqld --ft_min_word_len=1 --ft_stopword_file=''
```

Please note that once you change the fulltext system variable you need to rebuild all your fulltext indexes you want to affect.

Comment: but i am using shared server so i need to chnage this file for my sessions onlt. so is it possible.?

Comment: Change your hosting plan, to a dedicated machine.

Comment: i can use like instand of match against